# Installing the deprecated kinect stack

Tags: ros, kinect, installation, libfreenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install the old kinect stack that was based on libfreenect because I need it for a SLAM solution that I want to install.

Apparently, the stack source that I downloaded does not come with the freenect source, it should download it from github during make. The problem is that the old github repo for libfreenect is dead, so make breaks when it tries to download it. I downloaded libfreenect elsewhere, but I'm not sure if that will help. Obviously, the simplest solution of copy-pasting the libfreenect into the kinect stack dir doesn't work.

So, how can I successfully install the deprecated kinect stack?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29954/installing-the-deprecated-kinect-stack/) by [kameleon](https://answers.ros.org/users/1934/kameleon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2012-03-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-03-19**:
I think you're solving the wrong problem. What exact functionality does the old Kinect stack provide that openni_camera does not?

**Comment by [kameleon](https://answers.ros.org/users/1934/kameleon/) on 2012-03-21**:
I usually work with openni, but this specific SLAM application works with the old stack. I changed the makefile to look for the actual libfreenect repo, but now the connection still times out

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-03-21**:
If it only depends on the stack for (say) point cloud topics, topic remapping will let you use the new stack. If it needs a specific library to link against, that's trickier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can download the [libfreenect code](https://github.com/ros-pkg-git/kinect) and it still works fine. I seem to have all kinds of trouble with openni on OSX still.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1